# Print PHP variable name from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array like this:

```
$lang = array();
$lang['ITEM0'] = 'Home';
```

Ok now, if I save the variable name $lang['ITEM0'] into a mysql and I try to echo the query results, it prints me $lang['ITEM0'] as a string and not as a variable, so how can I print the correct value 'Home' of the variable name from mysql?
Here the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    echo $row['name'];
}

//result: $lang['ITEM0']
//I want result: Home
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us the portion of code where you save your data to the database. It probably a mistake on your side...

Comment: We'll need more code. Either you're `echo`'ing  out a single-quoted string and the variable isn't interpolating, or you stored it in the database single-quoted and it didn't interpolate...

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
 echo $row['name'];
}

//result: $lang['ITEM0']
//I want result: Home

Comment: @Maiori as mathieu said, how do you 'save' your `$lang['ITEM0']` to the database?

Answer (score 1):

To save not a variable but only index would be a lot more sane solution.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    echo $lang[$row['name']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

God knows why you're storing variables in a DB like that, but I assume you mean you have the rows name stored as literally `$lang['ITEM0']` (not the contents of that variable, the variable name itself.)

However, you'd do this:

`eval("echo " . $row['name']);`

But as other people have said, don't use eval. I would reconsider how you're doing this because it looks like a security nightmare waiting to happen.

BTW: If you feel you have to do it this way, at least use "Your Common Sense"'s method.

Answer (score 0):

I came here is search of the same thing and later realized I already knew the answer was just searching to hard for something that was already there.

In your mysql statement save the name of your variable as something unique to you. Instead of $lang['ITEM0'] save it as {lang['ITEM0']} or any other unique. for example I have {userid}. However in your example you could then use in your php code:
So now we'll assume

```
$lang = array();
$lang['ITEM0'] = 'Home';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
   echo $row['name'] ;
}
```

Here you get output of: I want to go {lang['ITEM0']}.
Change it to this:

```
$lang = array();
$lang['ITEM0'] = 'Home';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
   $var = str_replace('{lang['ITEM0']}', $lang['ITEM0'], $row['name']);
   echo $var;
}
```

You will get: I want to go Home

Hope this helps anyone who comes to this page.

Answer (score -1):

Use variable variables:

```
echo $$row['name'];
```

Note the TWO `$` signs.

PS. NEVER use `eval` ;)

Comment: I thought that would work, before I answered, but I tested it and it didnt work - ** $lang = $row = array(); $lang['ITEM0'] = 'Home'; $row['name'] = '$lang[\'ITEM0\']'; echo $$row['name']; // Error**